# Best way to store baseplates

Tags: storage

I recently acquired a large number of 32×32 baseplates (including the now rare tan ones) and old-style road plates that are no longer in their original packaging, but are still pristine.

What's a good (hopefully not too costly) way to store a bunch of baseplates? Currently, I just have them stacked in a cabinet, but I am sure they might get scratched if I keep them that way? Should I be sandwiching something between baseplates if I keep them in a pile? (Of course, a pile/stack makes it difficult to extract plates near the bottom, so better ideas are most welcome.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need such an extra care of the baseplates. I have a couple of used and abused baseplates with broken corners (from used bricks haul) and they still work. Yes, underside is scratched heavily, but the studs on top still hold the bricks.

My only suggestion would be - whatever you do, make sure baseplates do not bend while stored. Slightly bent baseplates still will be usable for your creations (like a buildings), however flat applications may no longer be flat.

Another observation I have is that even though baseplates do not have stud holes underside they still kind of "lock" when placed on top of each other and don't move too much. So I make use of that. Storing them vertically in a deep box proves helpful:

- easy to "lock" so they don't slide too much;
- easy to locate particular color/type you need;
- easy to remove without significant scratching (personally, don't consider them scratching this way);
- easy to transfer large numbers as single item/box.

Comment: Your suggestion to store baseplates vertically gave me an idea: since the four types of roadplates are all the same color, if I store them vertically, I can separate the different kinds with folder tabs (appropriately labeled) so I wouldn't have to rummage so much.

Comment: Also, your mention of broken corners reminded me of my old 48×48 gray baseplates (acquired way early in childhood); those always seemed to be more fragile than the smaller plates.

Comment: @高砂健吾 When storing them vertically, make sure they are packed tight together so they stay vertical. If you don't they will gradually bent/warp a little. I personally would rather stack them horizontally, like Alex says. I also have a fair number of space base-plates (with craters). I stack these as well, making sure I only stack plates with identical protrusions on top of each other (but I usually place flat plates below them on the bottom of the stack to save some space).